# HTTP Inbound adapter Differentiate between supported-methods

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-integration

I have a http inbound adapter defined like so -

```
<int-http:inbound-channel-adapter id="httpInboundAdapter"
channel="receiveChannel"
name="/inboundAdapter.htm"
supported-methods="GET, POST" />

<int:channel id="receiveChannel"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="receiveChannel" expression="@sayHello.sayHello(payload)" />
```

I would like to be able to differentiate between a GET and POST request and respond differently to them. How I can do that ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message on `receiveChannel` will have a header `http_requestMethod` set to 'GET' or 'POST'.

You can use `expression="@sayHello.sayHello(payload, headers['http_requestMethod'])"`, where the second parameter is a String.

To avoid hard-coding the literal, you can use `headers[T(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders).REQUEST_METHOD]`.

FYI `REQUEST_URL` and `USER_PRINCIPAL` are also populated; and, on the adapter/gateway, you also populate other headers with http request parameters or URI variables.